# Mulesfot - Create custom notification using CloudHub connector

Tags: connector, mulesoft, cloudhub

I tried to use the option "Create Notification" to CloudHub Connector.

I used this guide https://dzone.com/articles/cloudhub-connector-with-mulesoft.

But the notification didnt´apper...

I saw the flow... But i think it is correct.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWc5f.png)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are checking the notification on the correct Runtime Manager environment (dev, test, prod)? Each environment has their own ID and will receive separate notifications.

Also, there should no error logs related to the Cloudhub connector.

Comment: Yes @AngeloSandaga. I'm in the correct runtime Manager environment.